# In PostgreSQL Select * is taking a long time

Tags: postgresql

I have a 10 columns table in postgres and it has around 100 records. But `select *` is taking 3 to 4 seconds to come out, and that is just a `select *` from table. There are no joins on the table. While reading table data from UI it is taking a long time to come out.

Comment: The problem is on the UI or doing the query direct on DB? because a table with 100 record should only take 10 ms at most

Comment: Hi Chandra, welcome to SO. Since you clearly haven´t taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) please take a moment and look at this to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question, the complete query and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: where is the server? on the local machine or is it remote? how are you connected to it? how does this query's performance compare to other tables? ... the point of these questions (and points raised in earlier comments too) is to indicate we can only work with the information you provide, and you haven't provided much

Comment: thank you all for quick response. problem is from direct DB. from DB side  it self Query is responding in 3 to 4 secs. Server is in my local machine only. below are the explain stats  and table DDL 'Seq Scan on public.TABLE  (cost=0.00..32.73 rows=173 width=1338) (actual time=0.010..0.092 rows=173 loops=1)'
'Planning time: 0.597 ms'
'Execution time: 0.141 ms'

Comment: CREATE TABLE public.TABLE (    A SERIAL,    B text ,    C text ,    D text 
    E text ,    F timestamp without time zone,    H timestamp without time one,    J xml,    K text ,    L text ,    M text ,    N character(3)  DEFAULT No',    O character(1)  DEFAULT 'N',    P text ,    CONSTRAINT TABLE_pkey PRIMARY KEY (A)).

Comment: based on my observation,performance issue causing because of xml column. Is there any way to improve performance if we have xml or json columns in the table?